# Need to click two times to launch function (javascript)

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

Why i have to click twice to launch my timer ? 
Sometimes it works for first time, sometimes not. When i clear my cache, i need to click twice.
I'm blocked about that ...

My code

```
var COUNT_START = 10 * 1 * 60;
var count = COUNT_START;
var playing = false;
var play = document.getElementById('Reservation');
var reset = document.getElementById('annuler');

$('#count-timer').hide();

play.onclick = function () {
    if ((!playing) && (sessionStorage.length > 0) && (empty > 5)) {
        playing = true;
        $('#count-timer').fadeIn(1000);
    }
    count = COUNT_START;
};

reset.onclick = function () {
    if (playing) {
        playing = false;
    }
    sessionStorage.clear('nom_station');
    if (sessionStorage.length > 1) {
        $('#title-reservation').text('Votre réservation a bien été annulée');
    }
    count = COUNT_START;
};

function countdown() {
    displayTime();
    if (count == 0) {
        playing = false;
        sessionStorage.clear('nom_station');
        $('#title-reservation').text('Votre réservation a expirée')
        $('#count-timer').fadeOut(1000);
    } else if (playing) {
        setTimeout(countdown, 100);
        count--;
    } else {
        setTimeout(countdown, 100);
    }
}

countdown();

function displayTime() {
    var mill = count;
    var sec = Math.floor(mill / 10);
    var hours = Math.floor(sec / 3600);
    sec -= hours * (3600);
    var mins = Math.floor(sec / 60);
    sec -= mins * (60);

    if (mins > 1) {
        document.getElementById('count-timer').innerHTML = 'Votre réservation expire dans : ' + LeadingZero(mins) + ' minute(s) ' + ' et ' + LeadingZero(sec) + ' seconde(s) ';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('count-timer').innerHTML = 'Votre réservation expire dans : ' + hours + ':' + LeadingZero(mins) + ':' + LeadingZero(sec);
    }
}

function LeadingZero(Time) {
    return (Time < 10) ? "0" + Time : +Time;
}
```

In second time, i need to save my timer in sessionStorage, what is the best way to do that ?
If user refesh page, timer still continue.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

At the first click you bind the listener and then it starts to work. This is why it takes two times

Comment: Well, so what is the best way to solve this problem ?

Comment: $('#Reservation').on('click',function () {"your code"});